# Pass session to Angular from Node

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, mean-stack

Im creating a single page app. I have a sign in form in angular:

```
<div ng-controller="loginCtrl">
    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
        <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
        <button ng-click="senduser(user)">Login</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
MyApp.controller("loginCtrl", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.senduser = function(user){
       $http.post("/login", user).then(function(response){
            if(response){
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log("No Data");
            }
        });
      }
});
```

I can get the user authenticated by using `PassportJS`:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({username: username}, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false);}
        if (user.password != password) { return done(null, false); }

        return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

And the node route:

```
app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    successRedirect: '/loginsuccess'
}));

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.send("Try again")
});

app.get('/loginsuccess', function(req, res){
    res.send("You are Authenticated : ");
});
```

So far everything works. I want to redirect the `successRedirect` and `failureRedirect` to same path `\` but only have the session for the user who is authenticated. So based on the authentication, certain fields will be visible on the `\` page.

How do I do that ?

Comment: Your actual question is too broad, but I'll give you a bit of direction...  To do what you are asking, you would first need to send some identifying data instead of a string to the client.  In the client, you would need to store that data in the session storage.  somewhere else in the client app, you would need logic that checks for the presence of the data in the session storage and handles the display logic based on this data.

Comment: Ok. From node, where exactly I send the data from? Is it from `    successRedirect: '/loginsuccess'` or how? Im new to `MEAN`. Read somewhere that i need to store the session in a Angular service / factory. How Do I do that ?

Comment: you probably want to send some data instead of the `res.send("You are Authenticated : ");`, or at least in the client, do something with the session storage if you receive that string.

Comment: as for angular, there are multiple ways to handle session state, including using the `$window` object or using a 3rd party module like `ngStorage`.

Comment: I will have to send the user's id or username. How do I access that from `app.get("\loginsuccess")`?

Comment: this is exactly why this question is too broad.  It's not reasonable to discuss the multiple questions you have with this long and in depth process through comments.  It is better for you to attempt a solution, and then break it down into smaller components, and ask a focused question about what you have tried and what doesn't work with a single aspect of the process.

Comment: if you are really interested in a back and forth discussion to get you going, you might try the site's [chat service](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/);  there are generally people available at all times day and night, especially in rooms like JavaScript.

Comment: How do i move this discussion to chat? I'd like to get ur insights as you know what i want to achieve

Comment: I'm no expert on Node.js by any means, I just thought I could help you to craft a more answerable question, but I don't really know that I would be the best help with a full end to end answer.

Comment: No problemo. Thanks fr ur time

Comment: you can do `req.isAuthenticated()` on your desired route to check if user is signed-in / authenticated right ?

so you change the failureRedirect and successRedirect to `/` and then on that route handler you can do `if req.isAuthenticated { // do something for authenticated user} else { // do something else }`

P.S: `req.isAuthenticated()` is method added by Passport.JS to `req` object, please read Passport.JS documentation for better details and information.